# Save all content in a specific div as an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to save (or copy and paste) an entire div with dynamic information as an image. The div has information like final score, background image, and other custom elements.

Example:

```
<div class="saveme" style="background-image:url({{mainimg}});">
   <h1>{{Score}}</h1>
   <h2>{{Username}}</h2>
</div>
```

Ideally, when the button, SHARE ME, is clicked, the div is saved and inserted into an email or form which can be shared online. I have looked into https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ but am not sure how to incorporate it in angjularjs/ionic framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of `html2canvas` integration according the [docs](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html).

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.Score = 80;
  $scope.Username = 'My Username'

  $scope.saveMe = function(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('.saveme'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var src = canvas.toDataURL();
        $('<a href="' + src + '" download="saved.png">Download</a>')[0].click()
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="saveme" style="background-image:url({{mainimg}});">
    <h1>{{Score}}</h1>
    <h2>{{Username}}</h2>
  </div>
  <button data-ng-click="saveMe()">Save</button>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/gerena/edit?html,js

Comment: I'm an amatuer coder so I don't really understand where or how it is being saved? How would I just copy the div into a form (like email or social media sharing) and allow user to share and then remove the image?

Comment: You can't do this without saving the image on your server and that's require server side code.

Comment: So if I put the variable "src" you created into the form like so, <img src={{src}}/>... would that display the image from the saved location on the form?

Comment: This is an app I am working on so I might use server side or local storage depending on phone guidelines :)

Comment: You can set the `src` to the output image. BUT you can't send it via Email or share on Social because you need a public image. So localStorage will not gonna help in this case.

Comment: I see...do I have to maintain the image on my server or once it has been posted does the social network create a copy? I really don't want to take space on my server with hundreds of images of high scores

Comment: It's depends on the specific Social, but I'm afraid that most of them get the image from your server. If not each time but each day or something (like facebook etc.)

Comment: good to know...I guess I will have to rethink how I will integrate social sharing